# Apple Notes - quickly open multiple specific notes

Tags: macos, notes.app

Is there a way (Apple Shortcuts or other) to have a command that will launch the Notes app on macOS **and** open separate windows for multiple of your favorite notes?

**Use Case:**  I would like to have 3 separate notes open that I'm working on, and have them positioned nicely on the screen.  At the end of the day I close them all... and then tomorrow press a button to open all 3 notes again and restore them to their positions.  (Restoring window position is *a nice to have*... I'm mostly concerned with being able to open up multiple Notes in separate windows at the touch of a button.)

I don't even really care which language... could be Apple Shortcuts, AppleScript, or even Python. (Maybe one of these jumps out as the path of least resistance?)

Answer (score 0):

The following AppleScript will basically open three different existing notes (individually named "Note 1", "Note 2" and "Note 3" - rename them to the name of your notes) in three different windows:

```
tell application "Notes"
    activate
    open note named "Note 1"
    open note named "Note 2"
    open note named "Note 3"
end tell
```

---

You could even make a shortcut (in the Shortcuts app) that runs the above AppleScript. To do this, you have to make a shortcut in your Mac's Shortcuts app, add the "Run AppleScript" action and paste the above script. This shortcut could then be ran easily, as explained in [Run a shortcut while working on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/shortcuts-mac/apd163eb9f95/mac).

Comment: But that creates new notes.  As I described in my use case section, I want to be able to re-open 3 existing notes in separate windows.  (Like when you double click on note in the list view of the app... it opens that note in a separate window that you can position and resize.)

Comment: @JasonParker Oh. I've modified the script. Now it opens notes from their names. There is a command `open note named` which does that. ;)